# Ввод и вывод двумерного массива

Tags: python, массивы

Как реализовать ввод (с клавиатуры) и вывод двумерного массива в виде таблицы в Python?

Я начал изучать питон, но столкнулся с проблемой: не могу освоить ввод и вывод двумерного массива. Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Ну,мне выдаёт ошибку,которую я не могу исправить,т.е. не пойму как:
"IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: ты даже код не покажешь?

Comment: Подумал и выдал такую идею,вроде всё логично,но выдаёт уже упомянутую ошибку.
a=[]
for i in range(5):
  for j in range(5):
    a[i][j]=int(input())

Comment: @Семён ну правильно. в a[] нет a[0][0]

     a=[]
     for i in range(5):
       a.append([])
       for j in range(5):
         a[i].append(int(input()))

Comment: @alexlz Спасибо,очень помогло.Хотя вариант vostbur тоже оказался для меня полезным.А есть ли способ вывести этот массив в виде таблицы,чтобы строки были не в квадратных скобках,и не было запятых?
Обычная таблица с числами.

Comment: Ну если выравнивать не надо, то

    for i in range(5):
      for j in range(5): print a[i][j],
      print

Это для питонов 2.x

Comment: У меня вывело всё в один столбик,так и должно получиться?

Comment: Если предполагается выполнять математические операции над массивом, есть смысл создавать не list, а именно массив из numpy:
[pre][code] 
from numpy import empty

a = empty( (5,5) )

for i in xrange(5):
    for j in xrange(5):
        a[i][j] = input()
        
print a
[/code][/pre]

Comment: @Семён если вывело в один столбик, то забыли запятую после первого print

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [How to initialize a two-dimensional array in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2397141/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print [[raw_input() for i in xrange(3)] for j in xrange(3)]
```

Comment: Все получилось,всем спасибо за помощь,очень интересные варианты кода.

Answer (score 3):

Есть еще вариант использовать коллекцию с кортежем в качестве индекса:

```
a = {}
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        a[i,j] = int(input())
```

Вывести в виде таблицы можно так:

```
# первой строкой, только для python 2
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(5):
    print(*[a[i,j] for j in range(5)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы прочитать числа, разделёнными пробелами, из стандартного ввода в `numpy` массив:

```
import sys
import numpy   # $ pip install numpy

a = numpy.loadtxt(sys.stdin)
```

Если в строке больше одного числа, то двумерный массив автоматически создаётся (каждая строка это ряд), иначе можно вызвать `a.reshape(5, -1)`, чтобы 2D массив получить.

К примеру, ввод:

```
1 2
3 4
```

Создаёт:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])
```

Чтобы создать 2D Питон список для того же ввода:

```
L = [list(map(float, line.split())) for line in sys.stdin]
```

Результат:

```
>>> L
[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]
```

См. [Reading file string into an array (In a pythonic way)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052673/4279).